# "Type not found" after turning class into a haxelib

Tags: compiler-errors, namespaces, package, haxe, haxelib

**TL;DR**: Outside my project directory, installed with `haxelib dev`, and included in `Project.xml` like any other library, my library isn't seen by the Haxe compiler.  Inside my project directory it works fine.  Obviously other libraries don't have to be inside my project directory to avoid compiler errors, so what am I missing here?

I'm trying to release some code as a haxelib, by following [this page](http://lib.haxe.org/documentation/creating-a-haxelib-package/).

I originally had my package namespace as `flixel.addons`.  The code sat as part of a different project, under its `source/flixel/addons` subdirectory.  Before I started, the project it was part of compiled fine.

I decided it would be better not to invade someone else's namespace when releasing it, so I changed the namespace to `mynamespace` on the `package` line of my class file.  I looked at another haxelib for ideas, and saw that the library name can be different from the class path, which probably should be the same as the package namespace.  So I moved the code out of my project, into a new directory elsewhere:

```
mylibraryname
\-Readme.md
\-haxelib.json
\-mynamespace
  \-myclass.hx
```

Per the instructions, I ran `haxelib dev` with the path to `mylibraryname`.

In my project, I added `<haxelib name="mylibraryname" />` to Project.xml.  Where I used it, I changed the `import` lines from `flixel.addons.myclass` to `mynamespace.myclass`.

Now, trying to compile my project (in FlashDevelop, with Haxe 3.2.1) gives the error, `Type not found: mynamespace.myclass` on the `import` line where it's used.  The irony is that FlashDevelop added that line automatically with Ctrl+Shift+1 pressed with the cursor on `myclass` where it's used.  Further, I can press F4 on the red-underlined part of the `import` line, and it opens `myclass.hx` from its new location just fine.

That file contains:

`package mynamespace;`

And my project files that use it contain:

`import mynamespace.myclass;`

Meanwhile, the haxelib.json file has:

```
{
  "name": "mylibraryname",
  "url" : "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "tags": ["haxe"],
  "description": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1-alpha",
  "classPath": "mynamespace/",
  "releasenote": "...",
  "contributors": ["me"],
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Things I tried:**

1. Even though I believed it should be working at this point, I tried the next step of creating a zip file and using `haxelib install` on it.  No change.
2. I also happened to still have a directory `mynamespace` in my project, but I didn't really need anything in it anymore, so I deleted it.  No change.
3. Just to be sure there wasn't some typo somewhere, I plopped a copy of the `mylibraryname` directory (which had installed correctly in `...\haxe\lib\mylibraryname\0.0.1-alpha` and made a `.current` file with `0.0.1-alpha` in it, BTW) back into my project.  It compiled fine.
4. Even though it's not mentioned in the docs, I saw another library include a file `haxelib.xml` alongside `haxelib.json`, containing [this](http://pastebin.com/nYg59Z14).  With or without this file present, no change.  (Not even to code completion, which works fine listing my class' unique and inherited variables, but generates the exact same `Type not found` error in the Output pane as I get during a compile.)
5. `haxelib selfupdate`.  Was already up-to-date.  No change.
6. Windows restart!  Why not?  No change.

How can I get my project to compile?  Why doesn't Haxe see it when FlashDevelop and haxelib do, and when my lib's directory structure and `haxelib.json` are modeled after working third-party haxelibs and the docs?

Or am I misunderstanding something, and you have to test haxelibs in the context of a project, until they're released for real?  If this is the case, I'm not sure what exactly one is supposed to be doing with the `haxelib dev` and `haxelib install mylib.zip` steps.

Comment: Can you supply us with the package line in your library class, the import line in your  project code, and the contents of `haxelib.json`?

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho I don't believe I have the package or import lines wrong if it compiles fine when part of my project directory hierarchy, but I posted them as requested.  +1 for haxelib.json which I also posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem should be the `classPath` directive in `haxelib.json`.

Its value should be the relative search path for modules in the root/base package, not the path to your package.

Try changing it to `""` or omitting that directive altogether.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Wow, that was not at all clear to me from the documentation, and I had failed to notice that particular difference looking at other haxelib.json files.

Comment: @Kev it's great to hear that it worked! For future reference, the `classPath` field in `haxelib.json` behaves in a way similar to the `-cp` compiler directive.

Comment: Thanks.  Not familiar with `-cp`, but it's good to know.  (In general, it seems Project.xml and FlashDevelop together negate the need for actually dealing with compiler flags directly.)

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with FlashDevelop, only Lime / OpenFL's project xml format. `lime test <target>` on the command line does the same as compiling in FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your library and setting it up with `haxelib dev` seems sound, and I'm able to compile a project with a custom library created like that.

The only thing I can think of is that the `package` inside `myclass.hx` is declared incorrectly (maybe you forgot to adjust it when moving the file?).

Double-check that the first line in that file looks like this:

```
package mynamespace;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I meant when I said, "I changed the namespace to `mynamespace`."  But +1 because it was good to double-check this.

Comment: Updated post to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try doing this:

1. Create a folder with the name of your library in HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib (I'm gonna call it "example-lib", you can call it whatever you want).
2. Create another folder inside the example-lib folder with the title of the version name (e.g: 0,0,1 (note the commas)) and put your classes in it.
3. Create a file called ".current" inside example-lib folder (if you can't, try to copy one from another haxelib folder and paste into yours) and inside it, enter the version name (e.g: 0.0.1).
4. In your Project.xml, add

   `<haxelib name="example-lib" />`

Comment: When I ran `haxelib install mylib.zip` the steps indicated here were performed automatically--as I had said above, it had already installed it correctly in `...\haxe\lib\mylibraryname`.  But it was good to check the `.current` file, so +1 for that.  It existed and contained the name of the subfolder (`0.0.1-alpha`) in which my files were found in the structure above.

Comment: Updated post to clarify.